# Function of a dirac delta

Tags: dirac-delta

I would like to know if it is possible to compute something like

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(\delta(x-a)\right)dx,$$

where $f(x)$ is a function, or if it is even defined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you define $f(\delta(x-a))$ when $x=a$?

Comment: I would naively define it to be to $f(1)$ if $x=a$ and $f(0)$ otherwise, but I guess that is not a Dirac delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly, it's not defined, but there might be cases (other than $f$ being an affine function) where it can be given a meaning.

Comment: So, would it make sense to define something like $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)\ln[\delta(x-a)]dx=0$$, where $\delta$ is the dirac delta? The thing is I still need the property $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)dx=1$$.

Comment: @Carl. I cannot make anything meaningful out of that integral. The most natural would be $\ln \delta(a-a)$ with a value of $+\infty.$

Comment: I see. Well, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)(\delta(x-a))dx = f(a)$$
This comes from the fact that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx = 1$$

Comment: Yes, but the question is what happens if the delta is the argument of the function, not if it multiplies the function. Maybe changing the parenthesis would be clearer: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f[\delta(x-a)]dx$$